# Assets missing subfolders and images on the front end?

Tags: assets

for some reason my assets subfolders keep disappearing and then the images are removed from the front end.

They are still present on the server but assets no longer sees them.

Indexing doesn't cure the issue. Has anyone any advice?

Assets 2.1 and EE 2.5.5

Thanks
Guy

Comment: Hey Guy - are the Assets subfolders disappearing from the file structure, or just from the CP?  Are any changes being made prior to this change?  Is this a reproducible set of circumstances?

Comment: They are only disappearing from the CP. They remain on the server? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a site that I might be able to login to troubleshoot? If so, please email Super Admin and FTP details via support@pixelandtonic.com.  Thank you!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I need help please!

Comment: Hey Nefty - I responded to your email earlier.  Happy to help you through this!